# Excel Index Return multiple values matching multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, indexing, match

Index and Match wont return multiple values need to find a way, whether thats a function or VBA.

Essentially I have an Index and Match function that looks at two variables and then returns the corresponding Company that matches from a different sheet.

i.e you select "Australia" from a drop down and then "GOLD" from another drop down then the Index and Match will pull a company from another sheet that operates in Australia and mines Gold.
So far the function works but It only returns the first result and there may be more than one company and I haven't figured out how to return more than one result.

The code so far is as follows:

```
=INDEX(Datapage!B$2:B$280,MATCH(1,(A$8=Datapage!$C$2:$C$280) * (B$8=Sheet11!$D$2:$D$280),0))
```

I have also tried this one:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table26[[Location]:[Commodity]],SMALL(IF(Table26[Location]=$B8,ROW(Table26[Commodity])-ROW($D$2)+1),COLUMNS($B14:B14))),"")
the Data sheet has values in B2 - D280

But nothing happens and it only searches off one variable which is useless for this need.

B being Company name

C being Location

D being Commodity

I've attached some pictures for clarification

this is what the sheets look like

[image: Data page containing the names of companies]

[image: Search page]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is rather unclear, please read [ask], and [mcve] too - then [edit] your post to make a question that's answerable without starting a TeamViewer session. Cheers!

Comment: I've tried to explain as best I can, is there anything else I've missed?

Comment: Nice edits, I *think* I understand the question, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do - a cell can only have one value, how are you expecting a formula to "return more than one value"?

Comment: Also, since you're using a *table*, your formula should use [*structured references*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) that reference table columns by name, not range addresses. That way when the table grows you don't need to remember to modify the formula!

Comment: correct each cell only has one value, but in the table there are multiple values and I need the formula to spit out every value that matches the criteria, not just the first one in the list. I could place the formula in every cell on the results page but when it runs it is still only going to spit out the first result even though the cell above might have the same result. I need a version of the formula that returns all the matches, not just the first.

Comment: The MATCH function can only return one result.  See the [documentation here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a). I'd suggest trying to write a VBA function that doesn't stop at the first match. There are plenty of examples here on SO. [This search should get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+match+multiple). If you run into *specific issues* in coding it, come back and ask them along with a [mcve].

Comment: so a function of this sort modified to look at both criteria and then output  =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!E:E=$E$1,ROW(Sheet1!E:E)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!E:E))+1,""),ROW(A1)),"") would not work?

Comment: You need to write your own, in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested I figured out a function that doesn't require any VBA.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$B$2:$B$280, SMALL(IF($A$8&" "&$B$8=Data!$A$2:$A$280, ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$280)-1,""), ROW()-14)),"")
```

The first data in B column is the data I want returned if a match is found.

The "Small(IF(A..." function is combining the two variables I want a match looked for. Ie. A=Australia & B=GOLD etc etc and it'll look for a match on the next sheet.

The "ROW(Data..." compares the value in cell A8 and B8 with each value in the range. If a match is found,  "ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$280)-1" returns the number of the corresponding row (-1 is used to deduct the header row). If the compared values do not match, the IF function returns an empty string.

The  "ROW()-14)),""" function acts as an incremental counter. Since the formula is copied into cells A15, we add -14 for the function to return 1 for cell A15 (row 15 minus 14), 15 for cell A16 (row 16 minus 15), etc